# How to avoid copied code with the combination pgfplots/standalone?

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

I have a series of `pgfplots`-based figures that I compile to pdf images using the `standalone` package. I currently have one .tex-file per figure. The problem with this is that since it might just be the data file that changes between the .tex-files, this potentially involves a lot of copied code. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$]

\addplot[color=black]
table[x=x, y=y] {table1.txt};
%table[x=x, y=y] {table2.txt};
%table[x=x, y=y] {table3.txt};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above includes my current solution to the problem stated above: I simply uncomment the appropriate row depending on which .txt-file I want to import, and repeat and recompile until all the pdf files have been generated.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this, preferably automated (so that a bunch of different pdf files are compiled at once)? The closest I've come to a solution is the `multi`-functionality in `standalone`, allowing multiple-page outputs. But I'd prefer output in the form of multiple pdf-images.

Comment: Do you mean making the data file a variable and including it various data file names while keeping the code identical?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that changes is the filename of the data file.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I would handle using a command line tool (such as a perl script).  If no one posts a solely LaTeX solution and you're open to using command line tools, I can illustrate one approach I use.

Comment: Sure, sounds like a solution as good as any! If you would have the time to formulate it into a full answer, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: No worries, no rush at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a perl script that can achieve what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;
use strict 'vars';

foreach my $fh (@ARGV)
  {
    &MAIN($fh);
  }

sub MAIN {
   my ($source_data) = @_;
   $source_data =~ s/\.tex$//;

   open SOURCE, "<$source_data.tex" or die;
   my @source = <SOURCE>;
   close SOURCE;

   if (not -e "tmp_data.tex" )
     {
       open TMP, ">tmp_data.tex";
       close TMP;
     }

   open TARGET, ">tmp_data.tex" or die;
   foreach my $line ( @source )
     {
       print TARGET $line
     }
   close TARGET;

   system ("pdflatex standalone.tex");
   move ("standalone.pdf", $source_data . ".pdf");
}
```

Suppose the data you are using is in the following files:

```
data_01.tex
data_02.tex
data_03.tex
```

Also, as your standalone file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$]

\addplot[color=black]
table[x=x, y=y] {tmp_data};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you name the above script `publish.pl`, then
at the command line you'll call

```
$ perl publish.pl data_01.tex
```

This script will copy `data_01.tex` to `tmp_data.tex`.  If then compiles the standalone file using `pdflatex`.  Finally, it moves the `pdf` to `data_01.pdf`.

The script is written to allow you to iterate over the command line arguments to create all the individual `pdf` versions of the data you want.  I believe that as long as you have perl installed on your computer, this script should run find regardless of your OS.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you have a standalone document called `myplotfile.tex` and two data files `data1.dat` and `data2.dat` then you can change the file name before the includion of each instance of the same file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}


\begin{filecontents*}{myplotfile.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[color=black]table[x=a, y=b] {\myfile};
\show\myvar
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
a b
1 2
2 4
3 8
4 16
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
a b
2  1
4  2
8  3
16 4
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\def\myfile{data1.dat}
\input{myplotfile}

\def\myfile{data2.dat}
\input{myplotfile}
\end{document}
```

[image]